# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation changes height and width of a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios4, cgaffinetransform

Before rotation frame of UIView :- (123.46 326.855; 214.773 149.148);

After rotation frame of UIView:- (109.585 304.877; 242.524 193.104);

I used the following code:-

```
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotate);
    [contentView setTransform:landscapeTransform];
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `rotate` in the code above?

Comment: its changing everytime its not fixed

Answer (score 4):

Subview's frame is the smallest rectangle (in superview's bounds coordinates) which contains the subview (with transforms applied). So, it is affected by transforms.

```
UIView *parent = [UIView new];
parent.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

UIView *child = [UIView new];
child.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
child.center = CGPointZero;
    // at this point child.frame == { -5, -5, 10, 10 }

child.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
    // at this point child.frame == { -5 * sqrt(2), -5 * sqrt(2),
    //                                10 * sqrt(2), 10 * sqrt(2) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that you are trying to rotate a view by 90 degrees, and you have passed in 90 or -90 to the transform function.

The values have to be in radians, not degrees. There are constants available for the conversion, `M_PI` gives you pi (180 degrees) and `M_PI_2` gives you pi / 2 (90 degrees).

The frame of a view is going to be affected by any affine transforms - the frame is expressed in the superview's coordinate system, so it is always going to change to reflect this. The bounds rectangle will stay consistent to the original size.

If you rotate a view by 90 degrees, then the frame height becomes the frame width and vice versa.

Comment: i have passed in radians then also height and width are getting changed

Comment: Sorry for guessing! I've updated my answer.